# Can't figure out how to use puppet apt module

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to provision debian box with vagrant using puppet. And I want to add postgresql repository to sources list using puppetlabs/apt module. However, whatever I try, I keep getting this error:

`==> default: Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:18 on node packer-debian-7`

This is what I have in my default.pp file:

```
include 'apt'
class { 'apt': }

apt::source { 'pgdg':
    location => 'http://apt.postgresql.org',
    repos => 'main',
    key => {
        source => 'https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc'
   },
}
```

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong? I'm new to puppet and ruby in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you have a problem with `apt` instantiation. Use `class` (not recommended) or `include` (I recommend this approach: [explanation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html)). If you use `include`, remove quotation marks.

In summary, change:

```
include 'apt'
class { 'apt': }
```

to:

```
include apt
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you've faced is the incompatibility of the latest version of puppetlabs/apt with the version of puppet which is installed in your base box. The apt-module requires a puppet version >= 3.0. You can check the version of the currently installed puppet with the following command:

```
puppet --version
```

A working solution is discribed here: http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2013/01/19/upgrading-puppet-in-vagrant-boxes/.